# $n$-derivative of $m$-power of function

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, algebraic-combinatorics

There is well-known Leibniz rule generalization  for the $n$-th derivative of product of $m$ functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$, namely:
$$
D^n(f_1 f_2 \cdots f_m)=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n} \binom{n}{k_1 \,k_2 \, \cdots k_m} D^{k_1}(f_1)D^{k_2}(f_2)\cdots D^{k_m}(f_m).
$$
Is there any simplification of the formula for the case $f_1=f_2=\cdots=f_m=f$?

I hope there is a formula without the multinomial coefficients.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better than multinomial coefficients. The "generic" coefficient will have $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m$ all distinct; but for such coefficients, there will be no combination going on for $f_1 = f_2 = \cdots = f_m = f$, and so you'll still see the multinomial coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simplified version of [Di Bruno formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):

$${d^n \over dx^n} g(f(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n g^{(k)}(f(x))\cdot B_{n,k}\left(f'(x),f''(x),\dots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right),$$
which in the  case $g=x^m$ gives
$${d^n \over dx^n} f^m(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac {m!}{(m-k)!} f^{m-k}(x)\cdot B_{n,k}\left(f'(x),f''(x),\dots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right).$$

But be aware that the multinomial coefficients did nor disappear completely. They are inside the incomplete  Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$.